I can't access static images in my Vue application
I'm working with a VueCLI project using TypeScript, and I’m trying to access static images for use in a carousel. In my utils.ts, I’m using require to load images since importing them with import causes a "module not found" error. The issue is that require works fine for loading images in my NavBar, but it fails in my carousel component. I don't understand why importing images with import doesn’t work, and why require fails in one component but not in the other.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
utils.ts
const {diet}  = require("../assets/diets.avif");
const {user} = require("../assets/user.jpg");
const {activity} = require("../assets/excercise.jpeg");
const {report} = require("../assets/report.avif");
const {risks} = require("../assets/risks.avif");

export const getUserFromLocalStorage = (): User | null => {
  const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
  return user ? JSON.parse(user) : null;
};

export const setUserToLocalStorage = (user: User) => {
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
};

export const features = [
  { image: user, name: "Register your profile", description: "Complete your user registration, for a comprehensive tracking of your health" },
  { image: activity, name: "Track your activities", description: "Keep track of your activities and excercises" },
  { image: report, name: "Generate Report", description: "Get your comprehensive health report based on your profile" },
  { image: risks, name: "Do not let health risks catch you", description: "Stay ahead in your health with our suggestions" },
  { image: diet, name: "Eat healthy", description: "Stay ahead in your health with our diets" },
];


cards.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Image } from "@/interfaces/Features";
import { prop } from "vue-class-component";

defineProps<{
  name: string,
  description: string
}>();
</script>

<template>
  <div class="card bg-base-100 w-96 shadow-xl">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{name}}</h2>
      <p>{{description}}</p>
    </div>
    <figure>
      <img :src="img1" :alt="name" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>


carousel.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { features } from "@/utils/utils";
import Cards from "@/components/Cards.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <Cards v-for="(feature, index) in features" :key="index" :class="{'carousel-item': true, active: index === 1}" :image="feature.image" :name="feature.name" :description="feature.description" />
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>


Navbar.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import {storeToRefs} from "pinia";
import {useUserStore} from "@/store";

const logoImage =  require("../assets/excercise.jpeg")

defineProps<{
  isLoggedIn : Boolean,
  user :   User | null
}>()



</script>

<template>
  <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary" data-bs-theme="dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img :src="logoImage" alt="Logo" width="60" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-text-top object-fit-contain">
        Health Tracker
      </a>
      <div v-if="isLoggedIn"  class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Logout</button>
      </div>

      <form v-else method="get" action="http://localhost:8081/api">
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-2" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>


" importing them with import causes a "module not found" error." - what did you try? const {diet}, etc is a mistake, should be const diet
